# Recursive CTE produces no changes to initial query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Here is my current code:

```
--DROP TABLE #DataSet
CREATE TABLE #DataSet (
 [Client Number]    VARCHAR(6)
,[Account Caption]  VARCHAR(1)
,[From]             NUMERIC(18,8)       
,[To]               NUMERIC(18,8)   
,[ADDL UNIT RATE]   NUMERIC(18,8)
,[ADDL UNIT BASE]   NUMERIC(18,8)
)

INSERT INTO #DataSet 
SELECT '369229','0',0.01000000      ,100.00000000   ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',100.01000000    ,250.00000000   ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',250.01000000    ,500.00000000   ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',500.01000000    ,750.00000000   ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',750.01000000    ,1000.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',1000.01000000   ,1200.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',1200.01000000   ,1500.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',1500.01000000   ,2000.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',2000.01000000   ,2500.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',2500.01000000   ,3000.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',3000.01000000   ,3500.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',3500.01000000   ,4000.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',4000.01000000   ,5000.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',5000.01000000   ,6000.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',6000.01000000   ,7000.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',7000.01000000   ,8000.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',8000.01000000   ,9000.00000000  ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   UNION
SELECT '369229','0',9000.01000000   ,10000.00000000 ,6.55000000,1000.00000000   



 ;With 
 MaxVal AS 
 (
 SELECT  
 15000.00 AS MaxValue
 ,'0' AS [Account Caption (Pricing)]
 ,'369229' AS CLIENT_NUMBER 
  )
 ,RecursiveCTE AS 
 (
 SELECT 

       [Client Number]
      ,[Account Caption]
      ,[From]                                   = CAST([From]                                     AS NUMERIC(18,8))
      ,[To]                                     = CAST([To]                                       AS NUMERIC(18,8))
      ,[ADDL UNIT RATE]
      ,[ADDL UNIT BASE]
      ,MaxValue
  FROM #DataSet v JOIN MaxVal m on m.[Account Caption (Pricing)] = v.[Account Caption] AND m.CLIENT_NUMBER = v.[Client Number]

UNION ALL

SELECT 
       [Client Number]
      ,[Account Caption]
      ,CAST([From]                              + [ADDL UNIT BASE]      AS NUMERIC(18,8))
      ,CAST([To]                                + [ADDL UNIT BASE]      AS NUMERIC(18,8))
      ,[ADDL UNIT RATE]
      ,[ADDL UNIT BASE]
      ,MaxValue
  FROM RecursiveCTE
  WHERE [To] + [ADDL UNIT BASE] >= MaxValue
 )
 SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE 
 WHERE 1=1
 OPTION (maxrecursion 100)
```

I'm expecting the [From] and [To] to be built out by an additional 1000 all the way up until the [To] is greater than or equal to my max value of 15000.00

The results I'm expecting:

[image]

Instead I'm getting no changes to the initial results of the table. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Might `WHERE [To] + [ADDL UNIT BASE] < MaxValue` produce the result you want? At a glance it appears that there are no rows that would exceed (`>=`) `MaxValue` without several recursions. Aside: `WHERE 1=1` is superfluous.

Comment: Your syntax is not correct. Your CTE RecursiveCTE  should be ANCHOR UNION ALL ANCHOR JOIN RecursiveCTE. see link for better explanation  https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/